# Unzipping error - Unexpected end - Using ZipArchive

Tags: .net, vb.net, devexpress, unzip

I got the following Code:

```
  Dim ms = New MemoryStream()
  CustomReportVorlage.ExportToPdf(ms) 
  Dim bt2 = ms.ToArray()
  Dim outStream = New MemoryStream() 
  Dim archive = new ZipArchive(outStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, False)  
  Dim fileInArchive = archive.CreateEntry(String.Concat(String.Concat("Zugangsdaten_",src(0)("KURZBEZEICHNUNG")), ".pdf"), CompressionLevel.NoCompression)
  Dim entryStream = fileInArchive.Open()
  Dim fileToCompressedStream as new MemoryStream(bt2, 0, ms.ToArray().Length) 
  fileToCompressedStream.CopyTo(entryStream)
  fileToCompressedStream.Close()
  archive.Dispose()
  ms.Close()
  outStream.Close()
  Dim btFile = outStream.ToArray()
```

This works, I can unzip my file, etc. But I get "unexpected end" and due to that I can´t unzip the file in code.
How to solve that?

Comment: Are you saying that you can unzip the archive with a third-party program, but you can't unzip it with your own code? If so, then we would need to see unzip code that isn't working.

Comment: The code you have already works by accident, only because someone decided that `MemoryStream.Close()` doesn't clear the buffer (`MemoryStream.Dispose()` does actually almost nothing) - You have other weird stuff as `... new MemoryStream(bt2, 0, ms.ToArray().Length)`, when it should be `... new MemoryStream(bt2, 0, bt2.Length)` etc. -- What are you using to extract the entry? ZipFile or ZipArchive? Did you enumerate the entries before extracting? Compare with what Entry Name, at that point?

Comment: ms.ToArray() is the same as bt2. Thats just in there because I was testing a bunch of stuff. And I use 7-Zip for extracting and it works (atleast I can access the file), but I get the "unexpected end" error. And due to that error I can´t open it per code.

Comment: @Jimi - Do you have any suggestion how to improve my "weird stuff"? :D

Comment: In my previous comment: *The code you have already works by accident...*. Hence, the archive is generated and the content is readable. By accident, as mentioned, but readable. So the problem is not on your side. -- The code is quite *weak*; to improve it, you need to declare all the disposable objects with `Using` statements, so all streams are disposed in the correct order. -- It's important that you use `bt2.Length` to specify the length of the buffer. Verify the final name assigned to the Entry, make sure it's valid. -- I don't know how the final `btFile` is used, maybe the problem is there

Comment: Okay, thank you, I changed everything you said. I think the problem lies with DevExpress-Report Designer and not with my code. DevExpress seems to not close/stop writing on the file and due to that it can´t be fully written into the .zip-file.

Answer (score -2):

i suggest you to use the 7zip.exe with Shell("7zip.exe -extract...")
if this has helped you, accept my answer

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thats actually not quite the problem. I can unzip it myself, but I have a Third-Party-Software which does the unzipping (from our outsourced programmers) and due to that I can´t decide how it is done.